# IPTables string match redirection

Tags: linux, iptables, string

**The issue:** I am currently redirecting port 80 requests to another system on port 1000.

**This is done like so:**

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING ! -s 172.20.1.2 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.20.1.2:1000
```

However, when adding `-m string --algo kmp --string 'MSIE'` to filter packets with MSIE in them, they are being ignored due the prerouting only evaluating the first SYN packet(therefore missing the HTTP packets with the headers I am trying to evaluate)

**The broken rule:**

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING ! -s 172.20.1.2 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.20.1.2:1000 --algo kmp -m string --string 'MSIE'
```

**My Question:** How can I evaluate the HTTP Headers and redirect the packet or fire off a system event when a string match occurs?

Comment: Is the "broken rule" exactly how you are entering it? The syntax seems off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the man page:

> DNAT (IPv4-specific)
>
> This target is only valid in the nat table, in the PREROUTING and OUTPUT chains, and user-defined chains which are only called from those chains.

In other words: You lost, it's not possible. And that is obvious as you cannot change the target address in the middle of a connection (without repairing that at the new destination).

You want the application layer, you need an application. Redirect all packets to a (transparent) proxy which can decide what to do with the connections.